# How to group same elements of an array

Tags: javascript

An array having elements like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]`

How to group elements like this `[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], 6, [7, 7, 7], [8, 8], 9]`

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: Given the functions available to you for working arrays, and iterating over data, what do _you_ think might work? And what happens when you try writing code? If you haven't sat down and read up on how to use arrays or iteration, and you have no code yet: it's too early for asking on SO, [attempt to solve this yourself first](/help/how-to-ask) (including searching the web for others who already tried this) and then when you get stuck _with code to show for it_, that's the perfect time to post to SO.

Comment: @VLAZ yes array is sorted

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library:

```
Object.values(_.groupBy(array))
```

Sample:

```js
const result = Object.values(_.groupBy([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4]));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Result: `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4]]`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9];

let result = [];

while (arr.length) {
  result.push(arr.filter(e=>e==arr[0]));
  arr = arr.filter(e=>e!=arr[0]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If it's useful to you please accept/upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work!:

```js
arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]

let result = []

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] !== arr[i + 1])
    result.push(arr.filter(x => x == arr[i]))
}

console.log(result)
```